# SonarPLSQL-Trial Version

Tags: sonarqube

I am looking for SonarPLSQL trial version, as SonarQube community edition do not support SonarPlsql, I need to validate it for my team in POC activities. Is there any other alternate available?

Comment: Try to ask this question on [SonarSource Community](https://community.sonarsource.com/c/help) forum.

Comment: Could you replace in the title "SonarlPLSQL" by "SonarPLSQL"?

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to validate open source code (shown publicly), create a public project on [sonarcloud.io](https://sonarcloud.io/), it's free.
- If your code is closed source, you can also create a private project for free during 14 days on [sonarcloud.io](https://sonarcloud.io/)
- If you prefer to validate on premise, ask for a SonarQube [Developer Edition Trial License](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/editions/developer.html)